# How to automatically publish a HTML Chart in Excel using a VBA Macro?

Tags: html, vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to publish an Excel Chart automatically every minute using a VBA code.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceChart, _
 "C:\Users\file\graph.html" _
 , "Chart1", "", xlHtmlStatic, "DevXSample_16365", _
 "Graph1").Publish (True)
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), _
 "Auto_Open"
End Sub
```

I've grab this code in a website but when I run it Excel displays this error message: "Application-defined or object-defined error".
Does anybody know what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

.Publish is a sub, not a function so you'll need to take away the parenthesis around the True.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure without seeing your spreadsheet, but you will get "Application-defined or object-defined error" if "Chart1" is a worksheet.  If your source is `xlSourceChart`, then Chart1 must be a chart type (created by clicking on a tab and choosing Insert/Chart) not a worksheet type.