# Run Time Error 1004: Application-Defined or Object Defined Error

Tags: vba, excel

[image: ExcelSpreadSheet][image: VBAScrennshot]I am trying to record a macro which will create pivot chart out of excel data and here is the code that has been recorded:

```
Sub chart1()
 '
 ' chart1 Macro
 '

 '
Range("E1:F11").Select
Sheets.Add
In Debugger, code within the **** **** is shown in Yellow color
***** ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "data!R1C5:R11C6", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion12 ********
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("question1")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("answer1")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("answer1"), "Count of answer1", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("answer1")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("answer1").Orientation = _
    xlHidden
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("answer1")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$3:$D$6")
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$3:$D$6")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
End Sub
```

Why am I getting the Run Time Error 1004: Application-Defined or Object Defined Error when i try to run this macro ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in there?

Comment: @whytheq thanks, but can u help me with the issue instead.?

Comment: At the bottom... when I try your code, I get error 1004 but with a message that says it can't find the PivotTable source file. What does your error message say?

Comment: @OlleSjögren you mean its working fine for you?

Comment: No, accidentally hit enter... When the code is marked yellow - type `?Err.Description` in the immediate window (CTRL+G) to get the error message.

Comment: You need to provide more detail when describing the error in order to get usefull help...

Comment: Actually i'm new to this macros stuff. But i tried the above command you mentioned and here goes the result:   ?Err.Description
Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: OK, doesn't say more than your title, then. Is the pivot data in _"data!R1C5:R11C6"_?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18558/discussion-between-deadlock-and-olle-sjogren)

Comment: I guess yes. I have Added the screen shot. So pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the chart to be on a new sheet, 
you have to change the macro's "Sheet1" to new worksheet's name, 
The following macro should work for you, I have named the new worksheet as newWs

And fyi, your macro's error message I believe is due to trying to creating 2 pivot table of the same name on "Sheet1" is not allowed.

He also like to know what to create pivotTable base on Selected Area, so I have done modification to the code.

Edited: I Assume you select 2 columns each time

```
Sub chart1()
 '
 ' chart1 Macro
 '

 '
Dim selectedSheetName As String
Dim newWs As Worksheet
Dim rangeName As String
Dim header1 As String
Dim header2 As String
header1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Selection.Column).Value
header2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Selection.Column + 1).Value
selectedSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
rangeName = Selection.Address
Set newWs = Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    selectedSheetName & "!" & rangeName, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:=newWs.Name & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion12
newWs.Activate
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(header1)
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(header2)
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields(header2), "Count of answer1", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(header2)
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(header2).Orientation = _
    xlHidden
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(header2)
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(newWs.Name & "!$A$3:$D$6")
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(newWs.Name & "!$A$3:$D$6")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
End Sub
```

Comment: here idea is to create a macro which can be use to create pivot chart (most prob. Bar Chart) and most important it should be dynamic in nature. Your solution code seems to be static.

Comment: I just modified your code to make it work, 
So in the macro everything is static.    Which part of it you prefer to be dynamic?

Comment: i want this code to be capable of producing results for any selected/source data. Currently its producing the results for E- F columns whether you select G - H , I - J. See the Excel Screen shot to get a clear picture

Comment: see edited code, untested but should work, it it's not working please let me know

Comment: Sorry its not working and i'm getting this : This command requires at least two rows of source data. You cannot use the command on a selection in only one row. Try the following:

• If you're using an advanced filter, select a range of cells that contains at least two rows of data. Then click the Advanced Filter command again.
• If you're creating a PivotTable report or PivotChart report, type a cell reference or select a range that includes at least two rows of data.

Comment: Ok, which area did you select?

Comment: First i tested it against question1-answer1 then with question2-answer2 with 11 rows selected everytime.

Comment: And i think in your case,  you can come up with a better soluion by recording the bar chart macro only :)

Comment: Actually i'm doing it that way but always getting the error. Any how now its working fine. Thanks for ur time. :)

Comment: no problem, pivot tables and charts are annoying I sometimes get stucked in the same situation..

Comment: One last request: Is it possible to create a web page of the output.I can do it via recording but have no idea how to do it programatically.

Comment: Sorry, I have no such experience.

Comment: Maybe this link will help? If not, please raise another question I will upvote it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346707/how-to-automatically-publish-a-html-chart-in-excel-using-a-vba-macro

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18570/discussion-between-deadlock-and-larry)